# Xampp index file deleted by accident

Tags: xampp

My Xampp index file was just deleted by accident. Is there any way of 
recovering ?

I have tried looking for a backup.

Path is C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php

Thanx

Comment: For accessing database only , you can do it by "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/"...  I know its an old question but I have gone through this , thats why sharing ....

Answer (score 3):

Just recreate it and see if it works

Code is listed below

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
    exit;
?>
Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(
```

The directory path

C:\xampp\htdocs

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the value of that file, I would turn the system off remove the drive, and use data recovery software to attempt to restore the file. If it is hosted, you may want to explore options with your host.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is not an indispendable file, but I´d rather not run another installation, even if it´s just running on a localhost. Is there no way of recovering overwritten files ?

Comment: Problem was solved by reinstalling Xampp - and taking care in the future.